# What possibly can be stored in src attribute of an image tag?

Tags: html, image, security, dom, tags

What can I possibly put in `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag except image url? Is `<img>` `src` attribute any different from other tags with `src` attributes?

Comment: what else do you like to add in src ? absolute or relative URLs can only be used.like src="image.gif" or like src="http://www.example.com/image.gif"

Comment: how about javascript or xml?

Comment: What do, or can, you store in the `src` attribute of 'other tags'?

Answer (score 2):

Base64 data(Base64 conversion of an image) can also be stored in src attribute of an  tag.........

For example, this markup:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

produces this image:

[image]

Comment: Technically, that's still a "URI", or more specifically, a data URI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme